# How am I supposed to use bad luck as a disadvantage?

Tags: fiction, technique, plot, planning, mystery

So when I was thinking of a character, I tried my best to not make them a Mary Sue. We all know Mary Sue is the number one horrible character. As such I came up with ideas of characters that I can describe as; like the brilliant but lazy, brilliant/talented but unsure, and many more. I thought of a character that is talented but unfortunate; I thought it was a good one, but I'm not sure how to use their lack of luck as a disadvantage. I can't just throw random horrible things at them, and just shrug it off and say "they just have bad luck" as an explanation. How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Talented but unlucky: Sounds like me. In fact, Murphy L. is short for Murphy's Law!

Comment: Do you want realistic bad luck, or magic/fantasy level of bad luck?

Comment: Where does "We all know Mary Sue is the number one horrible character" come from, please? In 60 years of listening, I've never heard that, nor anything like it…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin A ["Mary](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MarySue) [Sue"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Sue) is a character that is too perfect. Originally it's a parody of a self-insert character in fan-fiction. -- Unless you're actually asking where the claim comes from that it's the worst type of character. That is probably subjective.

Comment: @towr The rest might be and how could where the claim comes from that it's the worst type of character be subjective? Are you suggesting there are three, or 12 or 93 possible derivations?

If that was clear, could https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MarySue still be right?

Your Mary Sue might work in your own domain and I suggest that here, she has no meaning…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad luck is a disadvantage, because it pits the universe against you as antagonist.

For example: You  need to lead an important meeting, to get a promotion. But your car breaks down, you miss the bus, your shoelaces break while tying them and your umbrella breaks while it's raining. You get to the meeting late, drenched and disheveled, and it's basically over. Fortunately for everyone else involved, Pete jumped and saved the meeting. Now he's the hero of the company and gets promotion, and you're relegated to tasks that are unimportant enough to trust you with.

When you have bad luck, anything you want to accomplish can get derailed by the tiniest of accidents. They don't need to be horrible, big events, they just need to ruin your character's life, a little bit.

Comment: Thank you. Though, do i really need an explanation to some of these bad luck causes and situation?

Comment: @Crimsoir You don't need to explain what's at the root of the bad luck (but if you're in a universe where things like bad karma or curses exist, you could). You also don't need to explain every misfortunate event with a complete causal chain (like ["for want of a nail"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Want_of_a_Nail)). But it's probably good to establish that it's bad luck, and not incompetence or something else. So for example if your character discusses their bad luck with a friend, he could give a whole list of examples, and, when asked, elaborate on the details of just one or two.

Comment: Watch the Lindsay Lohan film *Just My Luck*. Then you'll know all about bad luck.

Answer (score 1):

May we drop the character being "talented but…" and concentrate on "unfortunate"? Otherwise, would you not need to explain the difference between that and being "*un*talented but…"?

Lack of luck is a disadvantage, pure and simple… it doesn't need to be "used as" such.

The problem here is that yes, of course you can just throw random horrible things at them, and just shrug it off and say "they just have bad luck" as an explanation.

Larry Niven's hugely successful *Ringworld* series includes a character who for chapter after chapter gets herself and her companions out of terrible situations by no apparent means… which eventually leads the good guys to use Sherlock Holmes' methods to deduce that the impossible having been eliminated what remains, however unlikely, must be true. In their case, she is simply lucky.

That Holmes over-simplified the point doesn't matter: the *Ringworld* explorers rightly concluded she was not only lucky, but lucky beyond reason or ordinary belief.

George Cockcroft's *The Dice Man* has as its only point that the hero comes to make every decision in his life by throwing dice… literally living by luck, good or bad.

It might help to read *Ringworld* or *The Dice Man* and either way, there is no general reason why bad luck shouldn't be a major part of your story.

Quite separately, how do characters you might describe as like the brilliant but lazy, brilliant/talented but unsure, and many more, come into this?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have to explain bad luck that much. In fact, the usual problem is when you give your protagonist a lot of good luck. That is really problematic.

You don't say if your character is the protagonist. If it's the antagonist, bad luck could work the opposite way, making them too easy to defeat for the protagonist.

But let's assume you're talking about the protagonist.

Imagine your protagonist spends days preparing for a really trying challenge and then sails through it with flying colors... and it's all due to good luck. Rocky's opponent slips on a banana peel and breaks his leg in the first round... What a disappointment! What an anti-story. It will make your readers put the novel down.

Good luck is a story killer.

Instead, the general advice is to try and make most of your scenes end with anything from disappointing the protagonist to subjecting them to a pure disaster.

You can make that happen by choosing what parts of the story to make into full scenes and what parts to put in a shorter scene or even just mention in a short paragraph.

I.e. you show the struggle and the failures in full scenes, and then, to make the story move forward, mention the successes in passing... unless, of course, you can taint the success with a foreboding of future problems. Then go ahead and have a party while the serial killer sharpens his knives in the basement...

Where does all that bad luck come from?

The antagonist, their plans, and their henchmen.

Of course, you can throw in a bit of random bad luck, but the main adversary and the major cause of your protagonist's pain and suffering should come from an antagonist and their plan.

And then you show your protagonist trying to oppose that plan and every scene ends in some form of problem or disaster.

Readers want drama. Resistance, catastrophe, and bad luck will create that drama. Especially if it comes from a realistic antagonist with a plan.

Worth noting is that the antagonist, or the antagonistic force, does not have to be a person or group of people. You could make bad luck into the antagonist... however, the conflict will be easier to make organic and realistic if three-dimensional characters oppose each other.

The biggest problem you face if your protagonist has too much bad luck is that they might come off as comedic because of all the bad luck.

If you don't want that, you probably need to go deeper, be crueler and make people bleed more... Maybe... unless all that blood and gore is the reason for the comedy... then you push the breaks a bit instead. Cut the melodrama some...

Or of course, maybe remove some of the bad luck. Having lost their mother to murder might be all the bad luck a well-rounded character needs... (ask Kate Beckett and Harry Bosch...)